# Dropwizard configuration by not using .YML file?

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am new to dropwizard.
I want to know is their any other way to set the connection port, admin port, logger level and  all configuration parameters and not by use .YML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command like param when starting the application.

Its all within the [docs](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.4/docs/manual/configuration.html) within the Configuration section.

For example:

```
-Ddw.server.applicationConnectors[0].port=9090
```