# Dropwizard - Where is my YML file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, yaml, dropwizard

I followed the Getting Started guide of Dropwizard by executing the maven command below:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=io.dropwizard.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=java-simple -DarchetypeVersion=0.9.1
```

I was able to run, modify the project and all but I can't find any YML file in the project?

Just to clarify, is this something that I should create by myself or was I wrong in assuming that it will be generated by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I don't think a YAML file is generated by itself since Dropwizard can function without having one.

It's only when you **tweak an inbuilt configuration** or **add one of your own**, you'll need to specify it the `AppConfiguration` class and provide the corresponding values in `configuration.yaml` file.

**P.S**: There are other ways of providing the configuration like passing it as JVM args as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25713269/239094) but I wouldn't recommend using them.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have created my own YML. Now how do I tell my application which one to read? Does it do this automatically or should I say supply it as run param?

Comment: It's passed as a runtime argument to the main method of your Application class. E.g., java -cp myapp.jar org.web.myapp.MyApplication server path/to/configuration.yaml

Answer (score 1):

The simple command to start the dropwizard application is `java -jar <your jar path> server <path_to_our_yml>`

sever is also a default argument passed to start the dropwizard application.